# Solving $K + \frac{N}{F} + \frac{1}{MF^N}= 1$ for F

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification

I'm trying to solve the following equation in relation to F:
$K + \frac{N}{F} + \frac{1}{MF^N}= 1$.

With the following as symbolic context (but not needed for simplification):
$M =  \prod_{i∈L}{i}$,
$K = \sum_{i∈L}\frac{1}{i}$,
$L = {[4, 5, 6, ...]}$.

I *think* I've simplified it to the following, but no idea if this is right or if I'm on the right path or if this is correct: $ F = ((1-K-\frac{N}{F})M)^{-\frac{1}{N}}.$

Comment: The general trinomial can be solved [like so](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/418392/series-solution-for-general-trinomial).

Comment: This isn't solved for $F$, because $F$ appears in the expression on the right.  (Although you might be able to use this to approximate a solution by iteration.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Yes. This isn't solved for F. My question was exactly how to do that (the final snippet being my progress towards that, but being incomplete).
As Ethan explained below in their answer, for higher values of N, numerical methods will likely need to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you multiply both sides of your equation by $F^N$ and rearrange it you will find that you are looking for the roots of a polynomial of degree $N$. When $N=2$ it's a quadratic, and easy. There are complicated formulas for $N=3$ and $4$ but none for higher degrees.

In an application you may need numerical methods.